# How to add permissions to a queue to allow a user in a different account permissions on the queue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-iam

```
sqs.addPermission("https://sqs.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/111111111111/queueName", "remoteAccess",
        Arrays.asList("arn:aws:iam::222222222222:user/user.x@mycompany.com"), Arrays.asList(SQSActions.SendMessage.name()));
```

Should (IMO) add permissions on a queue to a user in a different account.

I get an error.

> Value [arn:aws:iam::222222222222:user/user.x@mycompany.com] for
>   parameter PrincipalId is invalid. Reason: Unable to verify. (Service:
>   AmazonSQS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValue;

Anyone know how to programmatically give a specific user in a different account access to a queue?

This is the same user arn as I see when I add the permission via the sqs web console.

Answer (score 3):

This section of the documentation has examples for cross-account SQS access policies : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-customer-managed-policy-examples.html

You need to apply a policy both on the queue level and to the principal in the other account.

For example, at the queue level

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": {
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": {"AWS": "111122223333"},
    "Action": [
      "sqs:SendMessage",
      "sqs:ReceiveMessage"
    ],
    "Resource": ["arn:aws:sqs:*:123456789012:queue1"],
  }
}
```

If you do want to grant access to specific user, group or roles, you can use the `Principal` field like this :

```
"Principal": {
         "AWS": [
            "arn:aws:iam::111122223333:role/role1",
            "arn:aws:iam::111122223333:user/username1"
         ]
      },
```

and in the other account, to the role or user who needs to access the queue (you can obviously limit the SQS API list, this just an example)

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": {
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": "sqs:*",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:*:123456789012:queue1"
  }
}
```

Comment: I want to only give access to a particular user on the other account. Not everyone there

Comment: and on that link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-customer-managed-policy-examples.html I'm trying to do something like example 4

Comment: That's not a problem, AWS Principal do not need to be a account, it can be a specific user, group or role.  I will edit the answer